# random color creation without change on page refresh

Tags: php, codeigniter

> get data list from the database:

```
foreach ($rowset as $key => $value)
{
    $colorrange=str_split($value->id);
    $findend=end($colorrange);
    $response[$key]['color'] = $this->get_color($findend);
}

function to get color:

public function get_color($findend){
    if($findend == 0){
        return '#455C4F';
    }
    elseif($findend == 1){
        return '#CC5543';
    }
    elseif($findend == 2){
        return '#4A572C';
    }
    elseif($findend == 3){
        return '#6E352C';
    }
    elseif($findend == 4){
        return '#E34819';
    }
    elseif($findend == 5){
        return '#283811';
    }
    elseif($findend == 6){
        return '#0E2F44';
    }
    elseif($findend == 7){
        return '#DF3D82';
    }
    elseif($findend == 8){
        return '#A8CD1B';
    }
    elseif($findend == 9){
        return '#088DA5';
    }
    else{
        return '#292421';
    }  
}
```

its a long code process i want to reduce that code and want it through loop and functions.

I want That for every Id whatever i will get from the database for that i want a random color. atleast color should not be repetaed before 30 id i am newbie here so please help me in this.

Comment: I think Its impossible in php .. Is it possible ??

Answer (score 0):

try this, it will gives you multi-color, you can handle it as you want.

```
 <?php
      foreach ($rowset as $key => $value)
                    {                
                        $colorrange=str_split($value->id);
                        $findend=end($colorrange);
                        $response[$key]['color'] = $this->get_color();
        }

 /****Random*Color**Function***/
    function get_color(){
    mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
    $c = '';
    while(strlen($c)<6){
        $c .= sprintf("%02X", mt_rand(0, 255));
    }
    $color="#".$c;
    return $color;
  }

?>
```

Comment: its working but color get change after page refresh .. i dont want it to change after refresh

Comment: store the color in random variable and call them . or store 3o color in database and call them respectively.

Answer (score 0):

just store the last select color id to your db or some place hten get use following code it's simple

```
public function get_color($lastid){
    $colors = ['#455C4F', '#CC5543', '#4A572C',.....];
```

return $colors[$lastid];
}